# Define and Deserialize empty classes

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I'm getting XML Data which contains an "envelope". For brevity, I'm focused on "Custom Fields" which is a collection of "Field".

Here is the part of the class definitions giving me a problem:

```
namespace Model.DocuSignEnvelope
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CustomFields", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
    public class CustomFields
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CustomField", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public List<CustomField> CustomField { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CustomField", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
    public class CustomField
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Show", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public string Show { get; set; } = "";
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Required", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public string Required { get; set; } = "";
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public string Value { get; set; } = "";
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CustomFieldType", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public string CustomFieldType { get; set; } = "";
    }
}

public static class DocuSignExtensionMethods
{
    public static T DeserializeXmlX<T>(this string input) where T : class
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using StringReader sr = new StringReader(input);
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
    }
}
```

if I get an empty list, happy times, it deserializes without issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                ...
                <CustomFields />
                ...
```

but if I get a list of "empty" Custom Field

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                ...
                <CustomFields>
                    <CustomField />
                    <CustomField />
                    <CustomField />
                </CustomFields>
                ...
```

It errors out with the Exception:

```
-       ex  {"There is an error in XML document (20, 7)."}  System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
-       InnerException  {"ReadElementContentAs() methods cannot be called on an element that has child elements. Line 20, position 7."} System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}
```

How can I tell the Deserializer to deserialize those fields as either an empty List (no valid entries) or a list with 3 empty CustomFields.

Comment: Change From : [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "CustomField", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]  To : [XmlEdlement(ElementName = "CustomField", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]    The property still can be a List,  XmlArray expects a parent tag and a child tag.  XmlElement only want one tag.

Comment: @jdweng i had it as XmlElement and it had the same issue if I'm not mistaken... I'll check in a few if i can. I switched to XmlArrayItem on a lark (another answer here somewhere). I'll verify that it still gives the issue. With an open/close tag if parses - but with "empty" children it dies hard.

Comment: I'll also add the deserialization part

Comment: Why do you have namespaces when the xml doesn't have any?

Comment: @jdweng It's been quite awhile since I created the code... but to my recollection, the XML was fed into http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ and the classes are what I staretd with with only minor changes. I'm actually fairly certain that's where I got the base classes. It seems as if you're saying the ", Namespace" parts aren't needed - and that's fine but probably another question :)

Comment: Added Deserialization methods, cleaned question a little.

Comment: Added Actual error messages

Comment: fixed mistake in my XML posting to correct error and add the xmlns.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the questions :) just solved my issue... give me 5 to verify...

Answer (score 1):

The following code works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EnvelopeInfo));
            EnvelopeInfo fields = (EnvelopeInfo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "EnvelopeInfo", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
    public class EnvelopeInfo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "EnvelopeStatus", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public EnvelopeStatus EnvelopeStatus { get; set; } 
    }
    public class EnvelopeStatus
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "RecipientStatuses", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "RecipientStatus", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public RecipientStatus[] RecipientStatus { get; set; } 
    }
    public class  RecipientStatus
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CustomFields", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public CustomFields CustomFields { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomFields
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CustomField", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public List<CustomField> CustomField { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CustomField", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
    public class CustomField
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Show", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public string Show { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Required", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public string Required { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CustomFieldType", Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
        public string CustomFieldType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Used following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnvelopeInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
  <EnvelopeStatus>
    <RecipientStatuses>
      <RecipientStatus>
        <Type>Signer</Type>
        <CustomFields>
          <CustomField />
          <CustomField />
          <CustomField />
        </CustomFields>
      </RecipientStatus>
    </RecipientStatuses>
  </EnvelopeStatus>
</EnvelopeInfo>
```

Comment: So the problem was... there are two spots that use the CustomFields. In one spot, the class was defined as a 'List<CustomField>'... in the other... it was defined as a 'string'. It was choking on the 'string'. It got switched to a 'List<CustomField>' and works.

Comment: There are two ways of handling arrays 1) EnvelopeStatus which requires two xml tags 2) CustomFields which require on one xml tag.